# Internal routes in a Play application

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

Imagine that I have a route in my Play application that returns some JSON :

```
GET    /getjson    controllers.someMethod()
```

I want this route to be available from within my application because I want to call it to get the JSON it returns and do something with it. **But**, I don't want it to be available from the outside. I don't want the http://mywebsite.com/getjson to respond to a client visiting my website.

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you define in the routes (`controller` layer) will be available to other services as RESTFUL endpoints.

For your case, you can simply make someMethod() as a method at `service` layer. There is not need to put it at the `controller` layer.

Comment: Could you add details to your answer? I can't identify the different layers you are talking about ..

Comment: Play framework follows MVC architectural pattern, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller. Roughly speaking, an architectural pattern separates components to layers w.r.t. the components' responsibilities. Controller layer, consisting of endpoints, is the interface to other services. Model layer is in charge of manipulating data, CRUD operations. Service layer lies in between. On the one hand, service layer provides services (methods) to the controller layer. On the other hand, service layer is supported by model layer.

Answer (score 1):

firstly, delete the following route item from conf

```
GET    /getjson    controllers.someMethod()
```

secondly, create another object whose definition is the same as the controllers.someMethod(), but not extends from Controller

last, delete the definition of the "controllers.someMethod()".

Then, the redefinition of the someMethod() is just available in the internal, but can not be called from the outside which means the "/getjson" url is unavailable and can not be reached.

Good luck.